# Next.JS How to pass parameters to a callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

so this is my code:

```
import Router from "next/router";
import React from "react";

export default function MainIndex() {
    return (<React.Fragment>
        <h1>Main Index Page</h1>
        <button onClick={() => Router.push('/family')}>Family</button>
        <button onClick={() => Router.push('/dynamic-id-page')}>Dynamic-id-page</button><br /><br />
        <button onClick={() => Router.push('/fav-games')}>World Of WarCraft</button>

    </React.Fragment>);
}
```

My question is: How can I create a function so I can use it as a callback for different routes.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking--you mean make "MainIndex" general-purpose? What needs to change? What would be changing it? How is it currently called? Can you not send it parameters as-is?

Comment: I want to make a callback function, which will do "() => Router.push()}" and I want to put a custom string to .push(), if it's possible of course. I just started learning Next.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "useRouter" :

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router"
```

then

```
export default function MainIndex() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const navigate = (event) => (url) => router.push(url)
...}
```

Then

```
<button onClick={navigate("/family")}> Family </button>
```

But keep in mind that this kind of "optimization" isn't really one... The inline function in your original code is easier to understand and [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://medium.com/@ryanflorence/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578)

Comment: isn't it the same that I have written? I mean instead of this: `<button onClick={() => navigate("/family")}> Family </button>`
I want to do this: `<button onClick={clickHandler}> Family </button>`
and I want to pass custom arguments to this `clickHandler`. But I don't know how.

Comment: @el1oz I see, edited. Note that to only use "clickHandler" without an argument, you'd have to look into the event received with the click. This would be very ugly and would serve no purpose

Comment: So I should leave as it is?

Comment: @el1oz Yes, your initial code is fine ; although nextjs recommands to use "useRouter" instead of "Router"